# Logstash - Drop logs containing kv value

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am unsuccessfully trying to drop logs based on the value of the kv value field.

```
 filter {
     if [type] == "cef" {
        mutate {
             add_field => { "tmp_message" => "%{message}" }
             split => ["message", "|"]
             add_field => { "version" => "%{message[0]}" }
             add_field => { "device_vendor" => "%{message[1]}" }
             add_field => { "device_product" => "%{message[2]}" }
             add_field => { "device_version" => "%{message[3]}" }
             add_field => { "sig_id" => "%{message[4]}" }
             add_field => { "sig_name" => "%{message[5]}" }
             add_field => { "sig_severity" => "%{message[6]}" }
        }
        kv {
             field_split => " "
             trim_value => "<>\[\],"
        }
        mutate {
            replace => { "message" => "%{tmp_message}" }
            remove_field => [ "tmp_message" ]
        }
      }
     if [FTNTFGTsrcintfrole_s] == "wan" {
       drop { }
}
```

[FTNTFGTsrcintfrole_s] is one of the keys that are parsed out by kv. If the value of the key is "wan", it should drop the log. That's not happening.

How can I filter out those logs?

Edit: Here is an example of the parsed data

```
{
                    "dst" => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
              "FTNTFGTtz" => "+0000",
         "FTNTFGTsubtype" => "forward",
                "message" => "%{tmp_message}",
                   "host" => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                    "spt" => "59975",
                   "type" => "cef",
 "deviceInboundInterface" => "ssl.root",
     "FTNTFGTdstintfrole" => "wan",
        "FTNTFGTduration" => "180",
      "FTNTFGTdstcountry" => "United",
        "FTNTFGTpolicyid" => "47",
      "FTNTFGTpolicytype" => "policy",
         "FTNTFGTpoluuid" => "801d40c2-3b60-51ea-d66a-293bf886d27e",
       "FTNTFGTeventtime" => "1633506791693710149",
"sourceTranslatedAddress" => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                    "dpt" => "8253",
                    "app" => "udp/8253",
      "FTNTFGTpolicyname" => "xxxxxxxx",
                   "tags" => [
    [0] "fortigate",
    [1] "_mutate_error"
],
                    "act" => "accept",
           "FTNTFGTlogid" => "0000000013",
                     "in" => "64",
   "sourceTranslatedPort" => "59975",
         "FTNTFGTsentpkt" => "1",
        "FTNTFGTtrandisp" => "snat",
     "FTNTFGTsrcintfrole" => "wan",
               "@version" => "1",
         "FTNTFGTrcvdpkt" => "1",
       "deviceExternalId" => "xxxxx",
      "FTNTFGTauthserver" => "xxxxx",
             "@timestamp" => 2021-10-06T07:53:11.729Z,
      "FTNTFGTsrccountry" => "Reserved",
"deviceOutboundInterface" => "wan1",
                  "proto" => "17",
                    "out" => "48",
                    "src" => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
             "externalId" => "870512",
           "FTNTFGTlevel" => "notice",
              "FTNTFGTvd" => "root",
                  "duser" => "xxxxx",
                    "cat" => "traffic:forward",
          "FTNTFGTappcat" => "unscanned"
}
```

Comment: Could you add some sample of your data parsed please?

Comment: @YLR Is there a folder where the parsed data is stored before it's shipped? The SIEM that I'm using doesn't actually show raw packet data.

Comment: You can just remove filter and put `stdout` output in json format, probably the easiest way if you don't know where to find the data.

Comment: @YLR added a sample

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thanks to @YLR and @Filip. The SIEM was adding "_s" to the key name when creating the field leading me to believe that that was the original key name and in turn what I was filtering for. After seeing the log output and realizing that wasn't the case, I corrected the filter and it worked.